# php:name array after variable

Tags: arrays, variables, for-loop

I have a problem using variable variables to name my arrays, inside a for loop.
This is my code

```
 <?php
 $which_innerarray = 0;


 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
            {
             $a{$which_innerarray} = array(1,2,3,4);
             $which_innerarray++;
            }

 print_r($a1);
 ?>
```

This is currently throwing up an error : undefined variable a1.

I probably have a syntax problem , but i can't seem to find it.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Richard Madson.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
${"a{$which_innerarray}"} = array(1,2,3,4);
```

But this looks like code smell. Why don't you use an array instead?

Comment: bingo!!! it worked @One Trick Pony ,,thanks a ton.. I cant accept this as the right answer for another 7 minutes :(,,stack rules.... but I'll do it for sure.. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way:

```
 <?php

 $which_innerarray = 0;


 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
            {
             ${'a'.$which_innerarray} = array(1,2,3,4);
             $which_innerarray++;
            }

 print_r($a1);
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks, this works as well and is a bit simpler and cleaner than the earlier answer. problem solved guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$which_innerarray = 0;
$a = Array();

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $a[$which_innerarray] = Array(1,2,3,4);
    $which_innerarray++;
}

print_r($a[1]);
```